# Is someone who is @mentioned in a direct message conversation they are not in still notified?

Tags: macos, macos-highsierra, slack

My Slack application (version 3.2.0 from the App Store) is running on my MacBook (running High Sierra 10.13.5).

I send direct messages to Persons A and B (I have invited both of them to the same direct message thread). In the message thread, I mention Person C by using `@person_C`. Is person C notified by the mention and will the message thread then be visible to person C?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've just tested this. Private messages are only visible to the people in the private conversation - if someone is `@mentioned` and they are not in the conversation, they will not see the message and will not be able to view other messages in the conversation.

That direct messages using `@mention` do not send notifications is also stated at the bottom of Slack's ["Mention a member" documentation](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/205240127-Mention-a-member):

> **Tip:** Using an @mention in a direct message with any member will not trigger a notification.

Additionally, since you cannot share messages from private conversations, the only way to share a message with someone outside of the conversation is to copy-paste it into a separate message to them.

So no, person C would not see the chat message with the `@mention` or any of the other messages in the conversation.